# mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to echo a statement in stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Edit_table` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Edit_table` (in_db_nm varchar(20),in_tbl_nm

varchar(20),in_your_query varchar(200)) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN


select concat('Table ',in_tbl_nm, ' not found');


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

this is what I get from the console when running it, it seems to always print the first line because that's the table column name, is there a way to remove this?

```
concat('Table ',in_tbl_nm, ' not found')
Table xxxxx not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Edit_table` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Edit_table` (in_db_nm varchar(20),in_tbl_nm

varchar(20),in_your_query varchar(200))
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

select concat('Table ',in_tbl_nm, ' not found') as DisplayData;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

This changes the header to 'DisplayData'

You can also start MySQL with --skip-column-names option to hide the column names